# Setting up and using environment variables in IntelliJ Idea

Tags: intellij-idea, environment-variables

I set up an environment variable (Under `IDE Settings -> Path Variables`)

```
 APP_HOME = /path/to/app_home
```

One of my tests is failing however with

```
 System.out.println("APP HOME: " + APP_HOME);
```

With

```
 APP HOME: null/
```

It does not look like that env variable is being read. What am i missing?

Answer (score 109, accepted):

**Path Variables** dialog has nothing to do with the environment variables.

Environment variables can be specified in your OS or customized in the Run configuration:

[image: env]

Comment: Make sure you restart IntelliJ after changing a system environment variable. It'd be nice to have a "reload" feature!

Comment: This field appears to be disabled when the what appears to be newer "Use project settings" option is checked. Is there a way to specify the environment variables in the "project settings"?

Comment: @jpierson I don't have such option, please provide a screenshot or more details.

Comment: Will these environment variables available to Gradle at build time?

Comment: No, the setting is only for this specific run configuration.

Comment: @jpierson for Maven, when project setting option is enabled, run configuration will use the settings that are specified [here](http://i.imgur.com/y8pZx3k.png). But it's offtopic since the original question was about application configuration, not Maven. If you have a different question, submit a new one.

Comment: It's tedious and error-prone setting up several env vars in each run config. There needs to be a way to set them for the entire project.

Comment: is it possible to put here `/etc/environment`?

Comment: image is broken

Comment: @LeiYang it's not, your ISP is probably blocking the image host used by SO.

Comment: But how to specify an environment variable for Tomcat server, say CATALINA_HOME? It config fields lack the field for environment variables. Eclipse does have the field. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26350970/tomcat-log-is-not-created-when-the-application-and-server-are-started-through-ec

Comment: @WebComer you can [pass environment variables](https://i.imgur.com/M5uo9SM.png) for Tomcat in IntelliJ IDEA.

Comment: @Sixro please share the screenshot like the one in the answer to show the problem.

Comment: In case your env variables are secrets, you probably store them in a key management tool like HashicorpVault. If that is the case, there is a maven plugin that fetches them for you, so you dont have to duplicate their declaration in your intellij run/debug config. I have added an answer for that particular use case.

Answer (score 9):

I could not get environment variables to work when IntelliJ `Build and run` property was using Gradle. I am not sure what the root cause is, but switching to `IntelliJ IDEA` solved the problem. Go to `Preferences` -> `Build, Execution, Deployment` -> `Build Tools` -> `Gradle`. Then change `Build and run using:` to `IntelliJ IDEA`.

[image: IntelliJ Run Preferences]

Answer (score 4):

If the above answer + restarting the IDE didn't do, try restarting "Jetbrains Toolbox" if you use it, this did it for me

Answer (score 3):

It is possible to reference an intellij 'Path Variable' in an intellij 'Run Configuration'.

In 'Path Variables' create a variable for example `ANALYTICS_VERSION`.

In a 'Run Configuration' under 'Environment Variables' add for example the following:

```
ANALYTICS_LOAD_LOCATION=$MAVEN_REPOSITORY$\com\my\company\analytics\$ANALYTICS_VERSION$\bin
```

To answer the original question you would need to add an `APP_HOME` environment variable to your run configuration which references the path variable:

```
APP_HOME=$APP_HOME$
```

Comment: Ignore the above. When you restart intellij it will substitute the path variable in your run configs with a hard coded value. Thanks intellij.

Answer (score 0):

This is not a direct answer to the question, but more an answer to the questions in the comments: "how to reload the env variables when they change ?".

If your env variables are comming from the OS, you unfortunately don't have a choice, as already said by @Neil McGuigan.

But if it comes from another key management tool like HashiCorp Vault, there is a maven plugin that allows fetching and injecting them into your JVM.
https://homeofthewizard.github.io/vault-maven-plugin/
So if you run your app as a maven goal on intelliJ, your env variables will be accessible.
Plus, It's config is project wide since it will be in the pom.xml, so no need to specify your env variables for each run/debug on intelliJ.

Answer (score 0):

This answer extends the answer by CrazyCoder and also the shows the latest IntelliJ IDEA UI. Click on **More Actions -> Edit -> Modify options -> Choose Environment Variables** from the drop down.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/E1vAQ.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iIVEa.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8KljE.png)