# AWS Linux vs Local setup for Spring-boot app postgres configuartion

Tags: postgresql, amazon-web-services, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

I have a properties file in spring-boot app which has postgres instance details for both the database hosted in AWS and one in local. 
Every time I checkout the code from git I have to comment the postgres AWS entries and uncomment the local postgres instance to work locally.
Again when I want to checkin, I have to do the opposite.
What is the smartest way to handle this configuration switching so that I don't have to do this every time.

N.B.: AWS deployment happens from github via Jenkins pipeline

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should provide your database parameters as environment variables in your IDE in the project setting ([for example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13749192/5380322)). Then set them in your application.properties as [placeholders](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-external-config.html#boot-features-external-config-placeholders-in-properties). For example:

```
spring.datasource.url=${DATASOURCE_URL}
```

Where DATASOURCE_URL is one of the env. variable.

So at your work you set your local parameters, and on AWS you set prod parameters.

Answer (score 0):

- use environment variables - you can use your local settings as default values and set environment variables for AWS usage on your EC2 instance
- use profiles and set active profile using command line parameter or environment variable on EC2 instance

Read more about:
- [externalised configuration in Spring Boot](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-external-config.html)
- [Spring Profiles](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-profiles.html)