# Google Pub Sub "Permission Denied" for project owner account

Tags: java, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-pubsub

I've been trying to get the Google Pub/Sub Java libraries to work using the Quickstart guides. None of them work as written, at least not for me. I'm working in IntelliJ, Maven framework, OSX, Java 8.

Take [this example](https://cloud.google.com/pubsub/docs/reference/libraries). I followed all the steps: Created a service account as Project Owner, installed the Gcloud SDK, set my GOOGLE_APPLICATIONS_CREDENTIALS envvar, and found that everything was hunky dory from the command line: I could create topics, publish messages, whatever I wanted.

Then when I tried to run the sample code:

```java
import com.google.api.gax.rpc.ApiException;
import com.google.cloud.ServiceOptions;
import com.google.cloud.pubsub.v1.TopicAdminClient;
import com.google.pubsub.v1.ProjectTopicName;

public class CreateTopicExample {

  /**
   * Create a topic.
   *
   * @param args topicId
   * @throws Exception exception thrown if operation is unsuccessful
   */
  public static void main(String... args) throws Exception {

    // Your Google Cloud Platform project ID
    String projectId = ServiceOptions.getDefaultProjectId();

    // Your topic ID, eg. "my-topic"
    String topicId = args[0];

    // Create a new topic
    ProjectTopicName topic = ProjectTopicName.of(projectId, topicId);
    try (TopicAdminClient topicAdminClient = TopicAdminClient.create()) {
      topicAdminClient.createTopic(topic);
    } catch (ApiException e) {
      // example : code = ALREADY_EXISTS(409) implies topic already exists
      System.out.print(e.getStatusCode().getCode());
      System.out.print(e.isRetryable());
    }

    System.out.printf("Topic %s:%s created.\n", topic.getProject(), topic.getTopic());
  }
}
```

It throws the ApiException `PERMISSION_DENIED`. The full stacktrace:

```
com.google.api.gax.rpc.PermissionDeniedException: io.grpc.StatusRuntimeException: PERMISSION_DENIED: User not authorized to perform this action.
    at com.google.api.gax.rpc.ApiExceptionFactory.createException(ApiExceptionFactory.java:55)
    at com.google.api.gax.grpc.GrpcApiExceptionFactory.create(GrpcApiExceptionFactory.java:72)
    at com.google.api.gax.grpc.GrpcApiExceptionFactory.create(GrpcApiExceptionFactory.java:60)
    at com.google.api.gax.grpc.GrpcExceptionCallable$ExceptionTransformingFuture.onFailure(GrpcExceptionCallable.java:95)
    at com.google.api.core.ApiFutures$1.onFailure(ApiFutures.java:61)
    at com.google.common.util.concurrent.Futures$4.run(Futures.java:1123)
    at com.google.common.util.concurrent.MoreExecutors$DirectExecutor.execute(MoreExecutors.java:435)
    at com.google.common.util.concurrent.AbstractFuture.executeListener(AbstractFuture.java:900)
    at com.google.common.util.concurrent.AbstractFuture.complete(AbstractFuture.java:811)
    at com.google.common.util.concurrent.AbstractFuture.setException(AbstractFuture.java:675)
    at io.grpc.stub.ClientCalls$GrpcFuture.setException(ClientCalls.java:492)
    at io.grpc.stub.ClientCalls$UnaryStreamToFuture.onClose(ClientCalls.java:467)
    at io.grpc.ForwardingClientCallListener.onClose(ForwardingClientCallListener.java:41)
    at io.grpc.internal.CensusStatsModule$StatsClientInterceptor$1$1.onClose(CensusStatsModule.java:684)
    at io.grpc.ForwardingClientCallListener.onClose(ForwardingClientCallListener.java:41)
    at io.grpc.internal.CensusTracingModule$TracingClientInterceptor$1$1.onClose(CensusTracingModule.java:391)
    at io.grpc.internal.ClientCallImpl.closeObserver(ClientCallImpl.java:475)
    at io.grpc.internal.ClientCallImpl.access$300(ClientCallImpl.java:63)
    at io.grpc.internal.ClientCallImpl$ClientStreamListenerImpl.close(ClientCallImpl.java:557)
    at io.grpc.internal.ClientCallImpl$ClientStreamListenerImpl.access$600(ClientCallImpl.java:478)
    at io.grpc.internal.ClientCallImpl$ClientStreamListenerImpl$1StreamClosed.runInContext(ClientCallImpl.java:590)
    at io.grpc.internal.ContextRunnable.run(ContextRunnable.java:37)
    at io.grpc.internal.SerializingExecutor.run(SerializingExecutor.java:123)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.access$201(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:180)
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:293)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: io.grpc.StatusRuntimeException: PERMISSION_DENIED: User not authorized to perform this action.
    at io.grpc.Status.asRuntimeException(Status.java:526)
    ... 19 more
```

The debugger tells me the `projectId` is set for the correct default project for that service account, so the service account is connected. And, as I said, I verified from the console that the permissions are in fact set to Project:Owner for that service account. So ... why the permission denied?

Thanks in advance for reading gnarly stack traces on my behalf.

Comment: Since you are running with no problem with gcloud this could be a problem with IntelliJ. Can you check whether you need to start IntelliJ via shell (as described in [this](http://are-you-ready.de/blog/2018/01/16/path-environment-variable-at-intellij-on-macos/) article) or set the GOOGLE_APPLICATIONS_CREDENTIALS variable in IntelliJ as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13749192/9251751) (this last one is rather old though)?

Comment: Bingo! Could you write this an answer so I can mark it as solved?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you are running with no problem with gcloud this must be a problem with IntelliJ. You should check whether you need to start IntelliJ via shell (as described in [this](http://are-you-ready.de/blog/2018/01/16/path-environment-variable-at-intellij-on-macos/) article) or set the GOOGLE_APPLICATIONS_CREDENTIALS variable in IntelliJ as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13749192/9251751).

Comment: Can you add the full answer, what env var to create exactly as links tent to die over time.