# Define GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS for google-cloud-speech , Java Desktop Application

Tags: java, google-cloud-platform, speech-recognition, java-audio

I am completely new using [google-cloud-java](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/google-cloud-java).

Trying to do some `Speech Recognition` using the [google-cloud-speech](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/google-cloud-java/tree/master/google-cloud-clients/google-cloud-speech) .

I have written the below code , but there is a problem , i don't know how to specify the credentials so i get the below error, no clue how to do it and searching the web 2 hours now :

```
java.io.IOException: The Application Default Credentials are not available. They
 are available if running in Google Compute Engine. Otherwise, the environment v
ariable GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS must be defined pointing to a file defini
ng the credentials. See https://developers.google.com/accounts/docs/application-
default-credentials for more information.
```

> Send audio from Microphone to Google Servers and return Text

```
package googleSpeech;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.HashMap;

import javax.sound.sampled.AudioFormat;
import javax.sound.sampled.AudioInputStream;
import javax.sound.sampled.AudioSystem;
import javax.sound.sampled.DataLine;
import javax.sound.sampled.Line;
import javax.sound.sampled.LineUnavailableException;
import javax.sound.sampled.Mixer;
import javax.sound.sampled.TargetDataLine;

import com.google.api.gax.rpc.ClientStream;
import com.google.api.gax.rpc.ResponseObserver;
import com.google.api.gax.rpc.StreamController;
import com.google.cloud.speech.v1.RecognitionConfig;
import com.google.cloud.speech.v1.SpeechClient;
import com.google.cloud.speech.v1.StreamingRecognitionConfig;
import com.google.cloud.speech.v1.StreamingRecognizeRequest;
import com.google.cloud.speech.v1.StreamingRecognizeResponse;
import com.google.protobuf.ByteString;

public class GoogleSpeechTest {

    public GoogleSpeechTest() {

        //Set credentials?

        //Target data line
        TargetDataLine microphone;
        AudioInputStream audio = null;

        //Check if Microphone is Supported
        checkMicrophoneAvailability();


        //Capture Microphone Audio Data
        try {

            // Signed PCM AudioFormat with 16kHz, 16 bit sample size, mono
            AudioFormat format = new AudioFormat(16000, 16, 1, true, false);
            DataLine.Info info = new DataLine.Info(TargetDataLine.class, format);

            //Check if Microphone is Supported
            if (!AudioSystem.isLineSupported(info)) {
                System.out.println("Microphone is not available");
                System.exit(0);
            }

            //Get the target data line
            microphone = (TargetDataLine) AudioSystem.getLine(info);
            microphone.open(format);
            microphone.start();

            //Audio Input Stream
            audio = new AudioInputStream(microphone);

        } catch (Exception ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }

        //Send audio from Microphone to Google Servers and return Text
        try (SpeechClient client = SpeechClient.create()) {

            ResponseObserver<StreamingRecognizeResponse> responseObserver = new ResponseObserver<StreamingRecognizeResponse>() {

                public void onStart(StreamController controller) {
                    // do nothing
                }

                public void onResponse(StreamingRecognizeResponse response) {
                    System.out.println(response);
                }

                public void onComplete() {
                }

                public void onError(Throwable t) {
                    System.out.println(t);
                }
            };

            ClientStream<StreamingRecognizeRequest> clientStream = client.streamingRecognizeCallable().splitCall(responseObserver);

            RecognitionConfig recConfig = RecognitionConfig.newBuilder().setEncoding(RecognitionConfig.AudioEncoding.LINEAR16).setLanguageCode("en-US").setSampleRateHertz(16000)
                    .build();
            StreamingRecognitionConfig config = StreamingRecognitionConfig.newBuilder().setConfig(recConfig).build();

            StreamingRecognizeRequest request = StreamingRecognizeRequest.newBuilder().setStreamingConfig(config).build(); // The first request in a streaming call has to be a config

            clientStream.send(request);

            while (true) {
                byte[] data = new byte[10];
                try {
                    audio.read(data);
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    System.out.println(e);
                }
                request = StreamingRecognizeRequest.newBuilder().setAudioContent(ByteString.copyFrom(data)).build();
                clientStream.send(request);
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println(e);
        }

    }

    /**
     * Checks if the Microphone is available
     */
    public static void checkMicrophoneAvailability() {
        enumerateMicrophones().forEach((string , info) -> {
            System.out.println("Name :" + string);
        });
    }

    /**
     * Generates a hashmap to simplify the microphone selection process. The keyset is the name of the audio device's Mixer The value is the first
     * lineInfo from that Mixer.
     * 
     * @author Aaron Gokaslan (Skylion)
     * @return The generated hashmap
     */
    public static HashMap<String,Line.Info> enumerateMicrophones() {
        HashMap<String,Line.Info> out = new HashMap<String,Line.Info>();
        Mixer.Info[] mixerInfos = AudioSystem.getMixerInfo();
        for (Mixer.Info info : mixerInfos) {
            Mixer m = AudioSystem.getMixer(info);
            Line.Info[] lineInfos = m.getTargetLineInfo();
            if (lineInfos.length >= 1 && lineInfos[0].getLineClass().equals(TargetDataLine.class))//Only adds to hashmap if it is audio input device
                out.put(info.getName(), lineInfos[0]);//Please enjoy my pun
        }
        return out;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new GoogleSpeechTest();
    }

}
```

---

> Following the given answers till now

My credentials.json looks like and i am getting the error:

```
{
    "installed": {
        "client_id": "",
        "project_id": "",
        "auth_uri": "https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth",
        "token_uri": "https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/token",
        "auth_provider_x509_cert_url": "https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v1/certs",
        "client_secret": "",
        "redirect_uris": [
            "urn:ietf:wg:oauth:2.0:oob",
            "http://localhost"
        ]
    }
}
```

Error :

```
java.io.IOException: Error reading credential file from environment variable GOO
GLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS, value 'D:/GOXR3PLUS STUDIO/XR3IA/creds.json': Error
 reading credentials from stream, 'type' field not specified.
```

---

> Update 3

Fixed the error following this link -> https://github.com/Triple-T/gradle-play-publisher/issues/141

Comment: The last message means, it successfully loads the `credentials` file but it is missing `type` field, look at an example of how it should look below.

Comment: @Dfor Tye Thanks i fixed the error following this link :) -> Fixed the error following this link -> https://github.com/Triple-T/gradle-play-publisher/issues/141

Comment: I am gonna update my answer. Make it as valid please

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Your credentials file look like this:

[image: Credentials]
Assuming you use `Eclipse`, Follow these steps

## First step

[image: first step]

## Second Step

[image: second step]

## Another way to load the file inside `Java` but please use at your own risk

```
public class SetEnv {

    public static void setEnv(Map<String, String> newenv)
            throws ClassNotFoundException, IllegalAccessException, NoSuchFieldException {
        try {
            Class<?> processEnvironmentClass = Class.forName("java.lang.ProcessEnvironment");
            Field theEnvironmentField = processEnvironmentClass.getDeclaredField("theEnvironment");
            theEnvironmentField.setAccessible(true);
            Map<String, String> env = (Map<String, String>) theEnvironmentField.get(null);
            env.putAll(newenv);
            Field theCaseInsensitiveEnvironmentField = processEnvironmentClass
                    .getDeclaredField("theCaseInsensitiveEnvironment");
            theCaseInsensitiveEnvironmentField.setAccessible(true);
            Map<String, String> cienv = (Map<String, String>) theCaseInsensitiveEnvironmentField.get(null);
            cienv.putAll(newenv);
        } catch (NoSuchFieldException e) {
            Class[] classes = Collections.class.getDeclaredClasses();
            Map<String, String> env = System.getenv();
            for (Class cl : classes) {
                if ("java.util.Collections$UnmodifiableMap".equals(cl.getName())) {
                    Field field = cl.getDeclaredField("m");
                    field.setAccessible(true);
                    Object obj = field.get(env);
                    Map<String, String> map = (Map<String, String>) obj;
                    map.clear();
                    map.putAll(newenv);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

and Call it like this:

```
Map<String, String> google = new HashMap<>();
google.put("GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS",
        new ClassPathResource("google_credentials.json").getURI().getPath());
SetEnv.setEnv(google);
```

For your last error. The problem was because your generated file is invalid.
You need to create a new valid one.

> From the API Manager, just create select "Create credentials" >
>   "Service Account key" and generate a new key for the Service that is
>   associated to your Google Play account.

Comment: Updated my question based on your answer i am having a problem with the credentials , i am looking for an answer here https://github.com/Triple-T/gradle-play-publisher/issues/141

Comment: The last message means, it successfully loads the `credentials` file but it is missing `type` field, look at an example of how it should look above.

Comment: You need to generate a file that looks exactly like the file above

Comment: Thanks i solved it , now i would like to make it platform independent with your method :) `setEnv` , i will accept your answer soon , need to do some testing . Love you :)

Comment: Not a problem. Just don't forget to make the answer valid for the others.

Comment: Love you :_) so much!!

Comment: I have a problem here , the .json will be inside the .jar file because the application is distributable https://github.com/goxr3plus/XR3Player , how can i get it from inside the .jar file .... i mean do i have to copy  it from inside out ?...

Answer (score 2):

I'm assuming you downloaded the credentials from the Google Cloud Console. They should be saved somewhere on your computer as a file.

You need to set the `GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS` environment variable so that it points directly to that file. Specify a path to that file. For example, if the credentials are called `creds.json` in the folder above your current working directory, you can set the environment variable to `../creds.json`. You can also specify an absolute path.

To actually set the environment variable, it's different per operating system. [Here's a good post](https://twilio.com/blog/2017/01/how-to-set-environment-variables.html) to help with that. If you're using Intellij, you can [set it directly in the run configuration](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13748784/setting-up-and-using-environmental-variables-in-intellij-idea).

Comment: Can i use something like `System.setProperty("GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS", "creds.json");` ? Actually which json i should download ?The one in section `OAuth 2.0 client IDs` which i created ?

Comment: I am trying also with `GoogleCredentials credentials = GoogleCredentials.create(new AccessToken("access_token",Date));` Can you provide some Java code pliz..