# Load variables in .yaml file from external sources

Tags: spring-boot, configuration-files

Is there a possibility to load variables from external file in .yaml configuration? Example:

```
  grant_type: ${GRANT_TYPE}
  client_id: ${CLIENT_ID}
  client_secret: ${CLIENT_SECRET}
  access_token_uri: ${ACCESS_TOKEN_URI}
```

GRANT_TYPE, CLIENT_ID, CLIENT_SECRET and ACCESS_TOKEN_URI to be defined and loaded from a file located in C:/config/, let's say.
Thank you!

Comment: did you find the solution to this?

Comment: @muzijack I defined those variables as environment variables

Comment: and how did you get them to a yaml file

Comment: The syntax remains the same in .yaml file. For test, you can set them in IntelliJ program configurations [like this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13748784/setting-up-and-using-environmental-variables-in-intellij-idea)