# How can I make Intellj use my environment variables?

Tags: maven, unix, intellij-idea, environment-variables

My `PATH` and `JAVA_HOME` are defined in `~/.bashrc`.

However, when  I launch Intellij from my Favorite icon and then  launch  a Maven Run Configuration, these variables are not thus defined. f I run the same `idea.sh` that is run from the Favorites icon, then they are recognized.

My `pom.xml` does some `exec`, so having these environment variables is essential.

The setting for "Include System Environment Variables" *is* checked. (As a test, I previously  defined env variable `FOOBAR`-- we see it is missing here.) [[image: env vars]].

How can I make this happen automatically, even when  I use the Favorites icon? The `desktop` file is given below.

```
[Desktop Entry]
Version=1.0
Type=Application
Name=IntelliJ IDEA Ultimate Edition
Icon=/hdd/executables/idea-IU-191.6707.61/bin/idea.svg
Exec="/hdd/executables/idea-IU-191.6707.61/bin/idea.sh" %f
Comment=Capable and Ergonomic IDE for JVM
Categories=Development;IDE;
Terminal=false
StartupWMClass=jetbrains-idea
```

Comment: Have you tried running maven with verbose output (`mvn -X ...`). It seems that ExecMojo should pick up system env variables (https://github.com/mojohaus/exec-maven-plugin/blob/master/src/main/java/org/codehaus/mojo/exec/ExecMojo.java#L361). On my PC, all env variables are passed to the executing program.

Comment: OK, I tried -X. What should I expect to see there. Maven itself, and also Exec, are NOT receiving the system env variables from the Intellij launcher. A simple ant echo command further confirms this.

Comment: I see full debug of ExecMojo, according to source code from first comment. (I wondered if you have some silently ignored errors). Another idea: Do you have `Include System Environment Variables` checked under `Build, Execution and Deployment -> Build Tools -> Maven -> Runner -> Environment` (I have it checked)

Comment: I tried with -X . The environment variables are not printed. But with  echo and other techniques, it is clear that Intellij is not passing system env to Maven

Comment: And the setting I mentioned?

Comment: There is no such checkbox  for me. See screenshot

Comment: Click on the icon on the right edge of "Environment Variables" text box

Answer (score 11):

- Go to `Build, Execution and Deployment -> Build Tools -> Maven -> Runner -> Environment`
- Find a little icon on the right edge of `Environment Variables` text box.
- On a pop-up widnow, check `Include System Environment Variables`

Comment: Thank you for pointing me to that checkbox. However, it was checked; but the system env  variables are still not in that list,so that does not make a difference. I learned something new -- this behavior is only when I launched Intellij from the Ubuntu Favorites icon

Comment: I cannot help any further (Windows user here)

Answer (score 1):

First click on marked button on configuration window,
[image]

then, check 'Include system variables' check box
[image]

Comment: Thank you for pointing me to that checkbox. However, it was checked; but the system env  variables are still not in that list,so that is not the solution.

Answer (score 0):

In case your env variables are comming from a seperate key management tool like Hashicorp Vault, there is a maven plugin that allows fetchin your secrets and making them available in your maven build.

Like so you don't have to duplicate their declaration in intellij.

Please see my answere [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77335858/1594088)