# To set Android_Home and JAVA_HOME variable every-time need to run "source ~/.profile" for Appium on MAC

Tags: macos, unix, terminal, appium, java-home

I am trying to Run Appium on MAC OS Mojave.
To see if my configuration is good I am using Appium Doctor.
It shows my ANDROID_HOME and JAVA_HOME is not set.

[image]

Once I set them in ~/.profile Appium Doctor shows all green that is everything is good.

Now the problem is every time I want to create new Appium Session or I close the terminal, then every-time I need to run "source ~/.profile"
Previously the setup was working fine.

[image]

How to solve this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Two Solution worked for me :

1st

Create Environment variable like Java_home and Android_Home in the IDE itself like if you are using intelliJ refer: [Setting up and using environment variables in IntelliJ Idea](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13748784/setting-up-and-using-environment-variables-in-intellij-idea)

2nd

```
Create a new file ~/.zprofile
Type there source ~/.bash_profile
Save and close
```

Now the environment should be saved in the profile and Appium configuration should be saved automatically

Answer (score 0):

This is not an Appium issue. Your environment is not saved in your profile.

~/.bash_profile is sourced by bash when we start in interactive login mode. That is typically only when you login at the console.

When you log in graphically, ~/.profile will be specifically sourced by the script that launches terminal. So ~/.bash_profile is not sourced .

You should save your environment settings in ~/.bash.profile instead

Answer (score 0):

You should set the required env vars in either `.bash_profile` or `.zshrc` files located in your users dir depending on if you are using bash or zsh as your choice of shell on mac/linux

Follow this by executing `source ~/.bash_profile` and the next time you open the terminal these configs should apply.

Sample config for android home:

```
export ANDROID_HOME=$HOME/Library/Android/sdk
export PATH=$ANDROID_HOME/tools:$PATH
export PATH=$ANDROID_HOME/platform-tools:$PATH
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are setting up the ANDROID_HOME environment variable on macOS Catalina, .bash_profile is no longer Apple's default shell, and it won't persist your path variables. Use .zprofile instead and follow the environment setup instructions in react-native documentation or others. .bash_profile will keep creating new file which won't make the path permanent or persist on closing the terminal on your system path.

To create a new path just do this in macOS Big Sur:

1. `sudo touch ~/.zshrc`
2. `sudo nano ~/.zshrc`
3. export all the path
4. ctrl + x and save
5. `source ~/.zshrc`
6. Check with `echo $PATH`